# How can I solve Image preview problem in livewire

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to make a ecommerce by following YouTube series and at the [18th video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcGAM05UMwA&list=PLz_YkiqIHesvPtvLl2Wz5FtuW44dBt199&index=20) I found a problem. When I am uploading a image for product image, I cannot find the image at the public path for this uploaded images are not previewing. I have added all my codes. plz help me anyone. Thanks in advance. Main technologies: Laravel->Livewire(temporaryUrl)

Here is the code of **web.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Livewire\HomeComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\ShopComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CartComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CheckoutComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\ContactComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\AboutComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\DetailsComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\CategoryComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\HeaderSearchComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\SearchComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\User\UserDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminCategoryComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminAddCategoryComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminEditCategoryComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminProductComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminAddProductComponent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
 Route::get('/',HomeComponent::class);
 Route::get('/shop',ShopComponent::class);
 Route::get('/cart',CartComponent::class)->name('product.cart');
 Route::get('/checkout',CheckoutComponent::class);
 Route::get('/contact',ContactComponent::class);
 Route::get('/about',AboutComponent::class);
 Route::get('/product/{slug}',DetailsComponent::class)->name('product.details');
 Route::get('/product-category/{category_slug}',CategoryComponent::class)->name('product.category');
 Route::get('/search',SearchComponent::class)->name('product.search');
// Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
//     return view('dashboard');
// })->name('dashboard');


// For User and Customer
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/user/dashboard',UserDashboardComponent::class)->name('user.dashboard');
});

// For Admin
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified','authadmin'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard',AdminDashboardComponent::class)->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/admin/categories',AdminCategoryComponent::class)->name('admin.categories');
    Route::get('/admin/category/add',AdminAddCategoryComponent::class)->name('admin.addcategory');
    Route::get('/admin/category/edit/{category_slug}',AdminEditCategoryComponent::class)->name('admin.editcategory');
    Route::get('/admin/products',AdminProductComponent::class)->name('admin.products');
    Route::get('/admin/product/add',AdminAddProductComponent::class)->name('admin.addproduct');
});
```

Here is the code of **AdminAddProductComponent.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Category;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class AdminAddProductComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $name;
    public $slug;
    public $short_description;
    public $description;
    public $regular_price;
    public $sale_price;
    public $SKU;
    public $stock_status;
    public $featured;
    public $quantity;
    public $image;
    public $category_id;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->stock_status = 'instock';
        $this->featured = 0;
    }

    public function generateslug()
    {
        $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name,'-');
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $product                    = new Product();
        $product->name              = $this->name;
        $product->slug              = $this->slug;
        $product->short_description = $this->short_description;
        $product->description       = $this->description;
        $product->regular_price     = $this->regular_price;
        $product->sale_price        = $this->sale_price;
        $product->SKU               = $this->SKU;
        $product->stock_status      = $this->stock_status;
        $product->featured          = $this->featured;
        $product->quantity          = $this->quantity;
        $imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp. '.' . $this->image->extension();
        $this->image->storeAs('products',$imageName);
        $product->image             = $imageName;
        $product->category_id       = $this->category_id;
        $product->save();
        session()->flash('message','New product has beed added successfully');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-add-product-component',['categories'=>$categories])->layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

Here is the code of **admin-add-product-component.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <div class="container" style="padding: 30px 0;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Add New Product
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="{{route('admin.products')}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right">All Products</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if(Session::has('message'))
                         <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
                        @endif
                        <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" wire:submit.prevent="addProduct">
                            <!-- 1st information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='name' wire:keyup='generateslug' >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 2nd information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Slug</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Slug" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='slug' >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 3rd information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Short Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea placeholder="Short Description" name="" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='short_description' ></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 4th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea placeholder="Description" name="" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='description'></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 5th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Regular Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Regular Price" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='regular_price'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 6th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sale Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Sale Price" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='sale_price' >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 7th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">SKU</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='SKU'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 8th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Stock</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" wire:model='stock_status'>
                                        <option value="instock">Instock</option>
                                        <option value="outofstock">Out of stock</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 9th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Featured</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" wire:model='featured' >
                                        <option value="0">No</option>
                                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 10th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Quantity</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control input-md" wire:model='quantity' >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 11th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Image</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="file" class="input-file" wire:model='image'>
                                    @if ($image)
                                    <img src="{{$image->temporaryUrl()}}" width="60">
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- 12th information -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Category</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" wire:model='category_id'>
                                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Product</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I changed the path in filesystems.php also.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('assets/images'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

plz help me anyone.

Comment: First, check on your `public/assets/images` folder and see if the file is stored there or not.

Comment: Have you checked inside storage folder ?

Answer (score 2):

It seem issue lies in

```
@livewireStyles
   Your code will be here........
@livewireScripts
```

Your don't use them. they are essential with livewire.

Other then that your seem perfect.

```
   <input type="file" class="input-file" wire:model='image'>
   @if ($image)
   <img src="{{$image->temporaryUrl()}}" width="60">
   @endif
```

If problem still not fixed please share web console for error.

Comment: Suffer this problem a lot mostly when i running a https project but getting a http using cloudflare rewrite and it get blocked but to mixed error check your web console for that. I suffer the same issue when I trying to running laravel with IIS.

Answer (score -1):

instead write

```
$imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp. '.' . $this->image->extension();
```

must be

`$imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp. '.' .` **$this->image->extention()**;

Comment: it's not working. bad method call coz here extention is a wrong spelling.

Comment: you're right. sorry, I felt in the same mistake as the video. So, first check if the public/assets/images/products/img.ext file is stored. Second, remember you must change the names of the files from 01 and 09 (if you followed the videos as exactly was made by youtuber)...could you please post also the folder structure for the public/assets/images public path?